# How do I set a Flutter TableRow in a Table to behave the way Expanded() behaves in a Column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-table

I have a `Table` in Flutter and I want to have it expand it's row so that the table takes up the full space that's available for it. Given that `TableRow` isn't a widget I can't use `Expanded` on it the way I would for Widgets in a `Column`. Is there another way to get similar behavior for a `Table`?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Table(
      columnWidths: const {
        0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
        1: FixedColumnWidth(12),
        2: FlexColumnWidth()
      },
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.bottom,
      children: [
        ...textMap.entries.mapIndexed(
          (index, entry) => TableRow(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: index == 0 ? 0 : 12),
                child: Text(
                  entry.key.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: appColors.textColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontFamily: entry.key.fontFamily),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: index == 0 ? 0 : 12),
                child: Text(
                  entry.value.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: appColors.textColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontFamily: entry.value.fontFamily,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

According to my information, you need to use the **Row** and **Columns** widgets instead of the **Table** widget and in addition to using the **Expanded** widget, or you will need to set a specific height for each row separately and it cannot be Flexible, Using **Container** in **TableRow** children